# Connect to Mysql remotely in centos 6.x server LAMP

Tags: mysql, remote-access, webmin

despite I've tried everything suggested in the forum I still can't connect to MySQL remotely.
This is my my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I've tried also adding the line bind-address = 0.0.0.0 but still doesn't work.
Then I deleted it because I've preferred leave the default configuration of my webserver and because I've read that, if is not specified, it is 0.0.0.0 by default.

I have the port 3306 open as you can see from my webmin module:
[Linux IPTables Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBMvP.png)

I've created the MySQL account named 'michele' as you can see from my webimn module [User Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XQ25.png)

and also I granted to michele the permissions for any database [Database Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edaWr.png)

and granted to any host all permissions [Host Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h18q.png)

To test my remote connection I'm trying to connect from MySQL for excel. that is the error [error MySQL fro excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAOJY.png)

> It is impossible to stabilize the connection. Incorrect response of
>   the connected party after the time interval or no response from the
>   connected host MY-IP-SERVER:3306

Also I want to inform you that this is my second attempt to connect remotely. In my first I made it! For a problem that doesn't deal with the remote connection I needed to reinitialize my server and here I am.

The first time I remember that in some configuration file I've put # for comment some line but I don't remember which and if it deal with my problem. Please help me I'm going to be mad!

Michele

Comment: Did you check if your firewall banned your ip address?

Comment: no how can I do?

Comment: I have run this commad
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n | grep "my-local-ip"

Comment: but nothing appears

Comment: You can from linux terminal `telnet (ip) 3306` for confirm that you have open port, for check your have this port open successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!
The problem was for the ipTable rule:
REJECT reject with icmp-host-prohibited
[rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsF6m.png)

so for solve the problem I deleted it.

on my server shell with root permission:

```
 # sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
```

[find the id rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMrZw.png)
and then deleted it:

```
 # sudo iptables -D INPUT 10
```